# Send one data in ajax don't work

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, forms, send

I am trying send one data to a data base, I am using the same structure that others, and this others works fine.

**Form**

```
<form action="" method="post" class="col-md-12">
  <select id="formu" name="cars" multiple " class="col-md-12">
    <option selected="selected">Multiple</option>
    <option>Multiple2</option>
    <option selected="selected">Multiple3</option>
  </select>
  <input id="send" class="col-md-12" type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

**ajax**

```
function showValues() {
  var str = $( "form" ).serialize();
  alert(str)
  debugger;
  $.ajax({  
    url: "recog_use.php",
    data: {
    'cars': str
    },
    type: 'GET'          
  });
} $( "form" ).on( "submit", showValues );
```

**recog_use.php**

```
include "conexion_leer.php";

$v='amigos';
$sql = "INSERT INTO `{$v}` (nombre)
VALUES ({$_GET['cars']}')";

if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {
 header('Location:../../Usuarios/mapa.html'); 
} else {
echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . mysqli_error($conn);
}
 mysqli_close($conn);
```

the file `conexion_leer.php` have the connection to DB

thanks you

Comment: So what's not working as you expect?

Comment: What is your problem? Where are you facing difficulty?

Comment: Do you have multible forms on that page? Look like you are grabbing the form on the form tag, try giving it an ID or class and grab it by that. $('form.youclass').on.('submit, showValues); or something like that

Comment: There is a missing quote : VALUES('{$_GET ...   and i would get that $_GET outside putting it into another variable to void nesting quotes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with this

```
function showValues() {
     var form_data = $( "form" ).serialize();
     $.ajax({  
          url: "recog_use.php",
          data: form_data,
          type: 'GET'          
     });
} 
$( "form" ).on( "submit", showValues );
```

in PHP Side

```
include "conexion_leer.php";
$v='amigos';
$sql = "INSERT INTO `".$v."` (nombre) VALUES ('".$_GET['cars']."')";
```

Comment: This fixes the javascript mistake, but still tries to use an array `$_GET['cars']` as a string on the server side

Answer (score 0):

Problem is in this line

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO `{$v}` (nombre) VALUES ({$_GET['cars']}')";
                                             Why This Extra^
```

Use [mysqli_prepare](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php#example-1875).

**recog_use.php**

```
<?php
include "conexion_leer.php";

$v='amigos';

$stmt = mysqli_prepare($conn, "INSERT INTO `{$v}`(nombre) VALUES (?)");
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, 's', $_GET['cars']);

if (mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt)) {
 header('Location:../../Usuarios/mapa.html'); 
} else {
echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . mysqli_error($conn);
}

mysqli_close($conn);

?>
```